# In C programming, How to create a datatype like 'int' which will hold longer numbers?

Tags: c

I am trying to solve **2^74207281**. But there isn't any datatype in C that could hold such a big number. Even '**long double**' is unable to do it. So, how can I **create a datatype** that can hold this large value? If there is no way to do this in C, do you prefer any other programming language?

Comment: C is probably not an ideal language to build this type of class in, but it's doable. An easier and already-existing solution would be Java's BigInteger: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: There is GNU MP library for bignums in C. https://gmplib.org/